# recursive_directory_iterator c++ no longer finds directories

Tags: c++, windows, function, directory

I'm trying to do a recursive search for files in the c:\ directory using c++, but I saw that the recursive_directory_iterator enters the first directory, does the recursive search, but when it enters the next directory it exits the loop and I'm not able to solve this problem.

my code:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string directory = "c:\\Users\\";
    auto d_init = filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(directory.c_str(),filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied);
    auto d_end = filesystem::end(d_init);
    auto error_code = std::error_code();
    for(; d_init != d_end; d_init.increment(error_code)){
        if(!error_code){
            if(d_init->is_regular_file()){
                cout << "File: " + d_init->path().string() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl << "End Here" << endl;
}
```

```
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\7z.exe
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\7z.exe.ignore
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\7z.exe.manifest
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\7zip.license.txt
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\checksum.exe
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\checksum.exe.config
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\checksum.exe.ignore
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\checksum.license.txt
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\shimgen.exe
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\shimgen.exe.ignore
File: c:\Users\All Users\chocolatey\tools\shimgen.license.txt

End Here
```

```
PS C:\Users> cmd.exe /c dir /A
 O volume na unidade C é Windows
 O Número de Série do Volume é 10FB-D95E

 Pasta de C:\Users

06/04/2022  08:44    <DIR>          .
06/04/2022  08:44    <DIR>          ..
07/12/2019  06:30    <SYMLINKD>     All Users [C:\ProgramData]
15/02/2022  08:20    <DIR>          XXXXXX4
15/02/2022  08:20    <DIR>          XXXXXX3
15/02/2022  08:20    <DIR>          XXXXXX2
15/02/2022  08:20    <DIR>          XXXXXX1
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text, copy-paste all text (including program output etc.) as text into your questions.

Comment: And what is `filesystem::end`? The end of a directory iterator is a default-constructed directory iterator (like e.g. `filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator()`).

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but I'm running your code on macOS, where it works as expected. Have you checked whether there are any errors, i.e., when error_code is not falsey?

Comment: I would recomend to test it first in you user folder, to be sure that there is not a permission problem.

Comment: @gerum i am running as nt authority system

Comment: @ViniciusFernandes Permissons can be strange, espacially under windows, so I would recomend it in a user folder, with only normal files and folders in it.

Comment: @9769953 yes but no error

Comment: And the same effect in a completely different directory?

Comment: @9769953 yes I tested in my user's directory and it does not show all folders and files

Comment: @gerum I'm trying in my user directory, but it still doesn't show all directories and files

Comment: @ViniciusFernandes Has you tried the hint to check the error_code?

Comment: @gerum yes i added the following line but i didnt get any error 

```
else{
            cout << "Error Code: " << error_code.message() << endl;
            Sleep(1000 * 5);
        }
```

Comment: ***07/12/2019  06:30    <SYMLINKD>     All Users [C:\ProgramData]*** May be related to the problem.

Comment: @drescherjm I test in c:\Users but it stopped before completing directories

Comment: drescherjm may have a point though. Did you try with the option `follow_directory_symlink` added next to your `skip_permission_denied` option?

Comment: @9769953 yes i tried

Comment: refiz o código e descobri que está dando o seguinte erro 
`filesystem error: cannot increment recursive directory iterator: Invalid argument`

o código:
`
for( const auto& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(argv[1],fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied,err))
        {   
            // note: in native windows file systems, make the comparison for extension case-insensitive
            cout << entry.path().string() << endl;
        }
        }catch(fs::filesystem_error &ex){
            cout << ex.what() << endl;
        }
`